# What is causing the exception HRESULT: 0xC0C01B22 when attempting to enlist a send port with a filter?

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013

This is a simple send port, in which I'm trying to setup a filter over a promoted property. Whenever I attempt to enlist this port, I get the following error:

```
===================================

Could not update Send Port 'SendPort1' in Message Box. Exception from HRESULT: 0xC0C01B22 (Microsoft.BizTalk.ExplorerOM)

------------------------------
For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=47400&ProdName=Microsoft+BizTalk+Server+2013&ProdVer=3.10.229.0&EvtSrc=Microsoft.BizTalk.ExplorerOM.Resources&EvtID=IDS_ERR_SENDPORT_UPDATE

------------------------------
Program Location:

at Microsoft.BizTalk.ExplorerOM.BtsCatalogExplorer.SaveChangesWithTransaction(Object transactionObj)
at Microsoft.BizTalk.ExplorerOM.BtsCatalogExplorer.SaveChanges()
at Microsoft.BizTalk.Administration.SnapIn.Forms.Common.ExplorerPropertyPagesContainer.CommitChanges()
at Microsoft.BizTalk.SnapIn.Framework.Forms.PropertyPagesContainer.Store()
at Microsoft.BizTalk.SnapIn.Framework.Forms.SheetFramework.Store()
```

The filter simply checks for existence of the promoted property in the incoming message. There's only [one post in MSDN forums](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5169dbb3-57ca-4391-8e60-eeb2dfa0c322/biztalk-admin-console-unable-to-enlist-send-port-x-exception-from-hresult-0xc0c01b22?forum=biztalkgeneral) about this exception: HRESULT 0xC0C01B22

Any idea what is causing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is in this page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/core/promoting-properties

The note there says the following:

**XSD Data Type of base64Binary, duration, ENTITES, hexBinary, IDREFS, long, NMTOKENS, and unsignedLong are not supported for promotion.**

Turns out, in our case, the promoted property is of `xs:long` type. I changed the element type to `xs:string` then the issue in the question went away.

It would make sense to prevent the promotion of the elements if they are of unsupported type, in the beginning itself. But we don't get to see any alerts during the promotion phase for such elements.

Hope this helps someone.